# Finding CPU and memory usage after running specific file

Tags: command-line, cpu, memory-usage, top

After running the python file, how can I get **CPU** and **memory usage** information using the `top` command for this file?
When I'm trying to find that, I wrote the base of code on my python file to know what the *PID* is by using the `os.getpid()` method, but when I get this *PID*, I search for it on the result of `top` command I didn't find anything about that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After running the python file, how can I get CPU and memory usage information using the top command for this file?

Wrong tool. `top` only shows active processes so "after" makes `top` unusable.

You can check memory usage from inside your script using `tracemalloc`. Or `psutil`

> The tracemalloc module is a debug tool to trace memory blocks allocated by Python. It provides the following information:
>
> - Traceback where an object was allocated
> - Statistics on allocated memory blocks per filename and per line number: total size, number and average size of allocated memory blocks
> - Compute the differences between two snapshots to detect memory leaks

and

> psutil is a library in python that allows for a developer to view the resource usage for a computer system. It provides a number of different functions and classes to make the task of analyzing the resource usage of a system easier.

Comment: Can I use it while I'm running Right? (i.e., top)

Comment: sure: open it in a terminal BUT your timings might be influenced by the python script going into background. Best to do is to do it inside the python script. You can then also evaluate functions themself.